# Is this a normal occurrence in backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I seem to be writing something like this when rendering views...

```
_.each @model.nestedcollection.models, (nestedmodel) ->
```

and I feel at some point i'll probably need to write something like...

```
_.each @model.nestedcollection.models, (nestedmodel) ->
    _.each nestedmodel.nestedcollection.models, (nestednestedmodel) ->
        #pass into new view
```

at times.

Is this normal or should I be dealing with this in a better way?

Comment: This related question had a helpful answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641707/best-pattern-to-have-models-listen-to-nested-models-and-collections

Comment: @Mark That's my other question. :)

Comment: I should notice who's asking next time O_o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normal. The backbone docs provide a [list of underscore methods for iteration](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-Underscore-Methods). You will see [_.each](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#each) at the top of the list. You should get to know these methods (if you haven't already) and use the most appropriate one.  Your second example may be a good use case for using _.each as your outer iterator and a more specific type of iterator (like select, detect, reject, or reduce) as your inner iterator. Choose the appropriate iterator function depending on your intention.

Answer (score 4):

one thing to note, other than what's already been said, is that the functions listed in the backbone documentation are directly available on the backbone collections.

you don't have to call `_.each @model.nestedcollection.models, (model) ->`, you can instead, call `@model.nestedcollection.each (model) ->` ... or whatever the right coffeescript syntax for that, is.

functionally the same, since it delegates to underscore's `each` method, but a little easier to type and read since it's directly on the collection.

Comment: drop the comma after the each and that's it.

Comment: oh right, cause in the call to `_.each` the models are a parameter, but in the call to `collection.each` there is no parameter other than the -> callback function.

Answer (score 0):

*update*
I prefer Derick's specific answer for handling your question. My suggestion is too vague.

I'm not familiar with backbone beyond reviewing the docs.

sorta OOP:
You could create an object that automatically iterates over it's composed internal models and renders them. This way any combination of them would automatically iterate over their internal models and render them.

sorta Functional:
Alternatively you could pass in a rendering function to all your nested models and have them each use it.