# Best pattern to have models listen to nested models and collections?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

Using Backbone.js what is the best pattern to have models listen to all of their nested models and collections all the way down?

Should I put nested models/collections in attributes? Should I create parental relationships and trigger events manually?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As with most things Backbone.js, you won't get a "right" answer to this, but I can share how I do it. With both models and views, I generally follow these guidelines:

- Views and models should be instantiated by the component that's "responsible" for them. For models or views with clear parent/child relationships, the parent model should instantiate, usually in the `initialize()` method.
- Parents should bind to child events at the time of instantiation.
- Parents should be "aware" of children, and can call child methods if necessary - I'd usually use this method over triggering a child event, as it's more explicit. I try to keep children independent of their parents, communicating upwards through events. So yes, deeply nested models would communicate through event chains.
- I sometimes `.set()` children as Backbone attributes, but usually just use plain Javascript attributes (e.g. `this.child`). It depends on the context. Using Backbone attributes provides `change` events, so if you need to monitor whether a child changes, use those. Backbone attributes also give you the ability to set at instantiation time, e.g. `var myModel = new Model({ other: otherModel })` - but because parents usually instantiate their children, this doesn't really apply in that case, and I usually use that pattern for non-hierarchical model-model relationships. In most cases, I set children as plain Javascript attributes.

Comment: nice answer. appreciate that there is more than one canonical best approach

Answer (score 3):

I really like @nrabinowitz' answer. he covered all the right details.

just wanted to toss out the idea of using something like Backbone.Relational which handles all this stuff for you: https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational

Comment: I ended up having similar to issues to this backbone-rel question, any ideas? I think I might be expecting different behavior from the automatically created models? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7685791/backbone-relational-events-not-firing