# Backbone relational events not firing?

Tags: javascript, model, backbone.js, coffeescript, backbone-relational

```
class TheModel extends Backbone.RelationalModel
    relations:[
        type: Backbone.HasMany
        key: 'subModels'
        relatedModel: SubModel
        collectionType: SubModels
        reverseRelation:
            key: 'TheModel'
    ]

themodel = new the TheModel({subModels:[{#stuff},{#stuff},{#stuff}]})
```

**I have createModels on** so `themodel.get('subModels')` returns a collection of models.

---

Now if I pass changed subModel data into `mymodel`

```
themodel.set({subModels:[{changedstuff},{stuff},{stuff}]})
```

Shouldn't `themodel` throw a `change` event? It doesn't for me.

---

More so if I pass identical data into `mymodel`

```
themodel.set({subModels:[{samestuff},{samestuff},{samestuff}]})
```

`themodel.attributes.subModels` throws `add` and `update` events, even though nothing is new.

I'm not sure why these issues are happening, any help would be great, thanks!!!!

Comment: So I think I figured out that backbone-relational's createModels functionality won't update nested models upon further sets of attributes to the parent module. It just clobbers them and adds new ones. So the reason this was happening was because only add/remove events were firing not change events. It's also why all those events fire when the data is the same. At least this is my thinking right now let me know if this is right or wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you reset a whole relation like that by setting a new collection, Backbone-relational will (at the moment) just replace the whole collection, instead of checking for differences. So it'll fire a `remove` event for all current `subModels`, then fire `add` events for each new one.

I do get `change` events though, with the following code (it would help if posted code contains a complete example though ;)

```
var SubModel = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({});

var TheModel = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
    relations: [{
        type: Backbone.HasMany,
        key: 'subModels',
        relatedModel: SubModel,
        reverseRelation: {
            key: 'TheModel'
        }
    }]
});

themodel = new TheModel({subModels: [{ id: 5 },{id: 7},{id: 8}]})

themodel.bind( 'change', function() {
        console.debug( 'change; args=%o', arguments );
    });
themodel.bind( 'change:subModels', function() {
        console.debug( 'change:subModels; args=%o', arguments );
    });
themodel.bind( 'update:subModels', function() {
        console.debug( 'update:subModels; args=%o', arguments );
    });
themodel.bind( 'add:subModels', function() {
        console.debug( 'add:subModels; args=%o', arguments );
    });
themodel.bind( 'remove:subModels', function() {
        console.debug( 'remove:subModels; args=%o', arguments );
    }); 


console.debug( 'set new subModels' );
themodel.set( {subModels: [{ id: 5 },{id: 7},{id: 9}] } )
```

This yields the following output:

```
set new subModels
change:subModels; args=[Object { _queue={...}, attributes={...}, _escapedAttributes={...}, more...}, [Object { id=5}, Object { id=7}, Object { id=9}], Object {}]
change; args=[Object { _queue={...}, attributes={...}, _escapedAttributes={...}, more...}, undefined]
remove:subModels; args=[Object { _queue={...}, attributes={...}, _escapedAttributes={...}, more...}, Object { length=3, models=[3], _byId={...}, more...}, Object { _related={...}}]
remove:subModels; args=[Object { _queue={...}, attributes={...}, _escapedAttributes={...}, more...}, Object { length=3, models=[3], _byId={...}, more...}, Object { _related={...}}]
remove:subModels; args=[Object { _queue={...}, attributes={...}, _escapedAttributes={...}, more...}, Object { length=3, models=[3], _byId={...}, more...}, Object { _related={...}}]
add:subModels; args=[Object { _queue={...}, attributes={...}, _escapedAttributes={...}, more...}, Object { length=3, models=[3], _byId={...}, more...}, Object {}]
add:subModels; args=[Object { _queue={...}, attributes={...}, _escapedAttributes={...}, more...}, Object { length=3, models=[3], _byId={...}, more...}, Object {}]
add:subModels; args=[Object { _queue={...}, attributes={...}, _escapedAttributes={...}, more...}, Object { length=3, models=[3], _byId={...}, more...}, Object {}]
update:subModels; args=[Object { _queue={...}, attributes={...}, _escapedAttributes={...}, more...}, Object { length=3, models=[3], _byId={...}, more...}, Object {}]
```

If you don't see these change events, could you check which versions of backbone and backbone-relational you're using?

Comment: I have the same problem on Backbone 0.5.3 and Backbone-Relational 0.4.0--Add and Remove events fire on parent relations.  Changes do nothing.